# Are there other phrases like 钉钉子, 种种子, and 扇扇子?

Tags: phrase

The phrases

> 钉钉子 (dìng dīngzi) "to nail a nail"
> 种种子 (zhòng zhǒngzǐ) "to plant a seed"
> 扇扇子 (shān shànzi) "to fan a fan"

are curious in that there's a single-character verb X applied to the noun X子.  It's also curious that the character X happens to be a 多音字 in all three cases.  I can't think of any other examples right now.  (I suppose there is 指手指 and 画画儿, which isn't exactly the same, but it's in the same ballpark.)

Just out of curiosity...

**Question**: Are there other phrases like 钉钉子, 种种子, and 扇扇子?

Answer (score 2):

因为爱著你的爱
因为梦著你的梦
所以悲伤著你的悲伤
幸福著你的幸福
因为路过你的路
因为苦过你的苦
所以快乐著你的快乐
追逐著你的追逐

This is a [Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blHIXiQiY0E). The verb is the same as the noun.

More examples

背背包，包包袱，跳跳绳，弹弹球，楔楔子，塞塞子，算算数，做作业*，贴帖子*，扣扣子，拉拉链，煎煎饼，烙烙饼，包包子。

吃点儿吃的，喝点儿喝的，玩点儿玩的。